# Java: Remove Comma & last name from the given full name string

Tags: java

I have a list of names such as :Doe, Jon
I want to remove the comma & last name to get the end result: Jon

Here is what I have so far:

1.

```
String result = info.substring(info.indexOf(": "), info.indexOf("CareWay"));
//prints: :Doe, Jon
```

2.

```
String newstr = result.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "");
//prints: DoeJon
```

I am not sure how I can extract Jon from variable result in step 1.

Comment: Answered but realized you have a *list* of those. What I think is missing here is the format of the list, i.e. how are the single `:name, surname` entities separated? Unless it's an actual `List<String>` listing all single entities?

Comment: rather than making everyone guess the input, why don’t you provide at least one example line of input with monospace formatting i.e. “code” format

Comment: I am not storing the results in a list yet. That is work in progress. This is an example from one of the field extraction that I am performing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always going to be in the format :`<Last Name>, <First Name>`, then

```
info.split(", ")[1];
```

If there can be any number of ", " then this is a more generic way,

```
String[] splitArr = str.split(", ");
System.out.println(splitArr[splitArr.length-1]);
```

Comment: I noticed that the solution worked, however, there is a space in the beginning of the result. eg. " Jon" (ignore the quote). Is there a way to avoid the blank space?

Comment: Split on ", " instead of ",", which is exactly what @6324 's solution stated.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

`String result = info.split(", ")[1];`

---

If you have a list of Strings:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("Doe, Jon");
names.add("Jon, Doe");
List<String> result = names.stream().map(name -> name.split(", ")[1]).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.print(result);
```

Output:

`[Jon, Doe]`

Comment: Thank you! I tried the solution provided by @Nishit and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
      String info=": Doe, JonCareWay";
      String result = info.substring(info.indexOf(": "), 
      info.indexOf("CareWay")).split(",")[1];
      System.out.println(result);
      String[] splitArr = result.split(", ");
      System.out.println(splitArr[splitArr.length-1]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the solution provided by @Nishit and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a guaranteed format for step 2 as shown, your regex is close to what you want.

For replacement with `""` you regex should be:

```
" :\w+, "
```

Or a little more dynamically for characters before the last name:

```
"\W*\w+, "
```

If you want super simple:

```
".*, "
```

(In all cases, note the space[s], which you could replace with `\s`)

(If you don't want numbers, or the under-score, instead of `\w` use `[a-zA-Z]`)
(Similar case for `\W`)

Where:

- `\w` is any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `\W` is any non-word character `[^\w]`

I recommend [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) for testing out regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the solution provided by @Nishit and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String result = info.substring(info.indexOf(" "),info.length());
```

It will give you result Jon